# Different CORS settings for different paths?

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

I have created an application with [Go](https://go.dev/) in [Gin-Gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin). In my frontend ([Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/)/[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)) I always get a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/notion/database' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I commented out all the endpoints of my application and built only these two endpoints step by step. With the same CORS config, the endpoints suddenly worked. I built the endpoints more and more and found the following error:

The `/api/v1/notion` endpoint works and I can access it. The `/api/v1/notion/database` endpoint does not work and returns the above CORS error. I use the official [CORS middleware](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) from Gin-Gonic.

```golang
func main(){
  r := gin.Default()
  r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Authorization", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
  }))
  r.GET("/api/v1/notion", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, " OK")
  })
  r.GET("/api/v1/notion/database", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, " OK")
  })
  r.Run(":8081")
}
```

The reqeust I send from the frontend looks like this for both:

```js
async function sendOwnRequest(){
  const url1 = 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/notion'
  const url2 = 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/notion/database'
  const bearer = 'Bearer ey...'

  const response = await window.fetch(url1, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': bearer},
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
  })

  const response = await window.fetch(url2, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': bearer},
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
  })
}
```

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be, because both should be 100% identical except for the URL path. Is there a CORS property which I have to set?

---

Versions:

- go version: `go1.20 darwin/arm64`
- go list -m github.com/gin-gonic/gin: `v1.9.1`
- go list -m github.com/gin-contrib/cors: `v1.4.0`
- node --version: `v18.17.0`
- npm --version: `9.6.7`

Comment: As an update, I have recreated the two endpoints on a complete new Go instance, where the endpoints work. However, when I comment out all the code from my project and do a go mod tidy in my main project, the CORS error still comes up.

Answer (score 0):

On the go server side code  `r.Run("8081")` should be  `r.Run(":8081") // Note the colon before the port number`

Apart from this i dont see any issue with the code, client code also looks good

Edit:
Ah, I think you might have missed the OPTIONS preflight check by browsers? just before making call to `r.GET` ?

```
r.OPTIONS("/api/v1/notion", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Status(http.StatusOK)
})
```

Comment: In my code it is like this with the colon (and works), however when I minimized the code I overlooked it. I have adjusted it in my code example. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix my problem, I added the `r.OPTIONS()` before the other reqeust however the result remains the same. Also I never had to manually create an `r.OPTIONS()` in my previous APIs, because it always worked by default.

Comment: ok, let me recheck

Comment: try the request with postman and see if that works? I mean to try using differnet client like postman or curl ? and instead of localhost try with 127.0.01 everywhere both client and server and see that works

Comment: Both endpoints work via Postman.

Comment: ok, from postman there is a option to generate client code in js , pls generate code use teh same code in you client to see if that works

Comment: Have generated the JS code but it does not work either. It comes the same CORS error.